# What does it mean when no implementation is provided by the class/struct that adopts a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, swift-protocols

As far as I understand, a protocol is a blueprint for properties, methods, and other requirements without the actual implementation.  The conformance to a protocol means providing the actual implementation of the blueprint.  But, I frequently see classes and struct's adopting a protocol without actually providing the implementation.

For example:

```swift
class Item: Codable {
    var title: String = ""
    var done: Bool = false
}

var itemArray = [Item]()
let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(itemArray)
    try data.write(to: dataFilePath!)
} catch {
    print("Error encoding item array, \(error)")
}
```

The `Item` class here adopts the `Codable` protocol and the instance of the class is used as an argument to the instance method of `PropertyListEncoder()`.  However, no implementation for the `Codable` protocol was provided or used in this process.

Comment: For what it’s worth if Class Item is used in a real project and not just testing you may want to consider implementing it as a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are protocols that offer what is called automatic synthesis. In the case of `Codable` that means that as long as the properties of `Item` conform to `Codable`, methods such as `init(from:)` or `encode(to:)` are automatically added to that type.

> As long as all of its properties are Codable, any custom type can also be Codable.

[Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Another great example is `Equatable`, see [Conforming to the Equatable Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable)

Automatic synthesis is done via [protocol extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521).

Answer (score 1):

The `Codable` protocol is one of a few protocols (`Equatable`, `Hashable`) that can be synthesized by the compiler so long as all properties of a type also conform to that protocol. This means that the compiler is generating the implementation for the protocol that you noticed was missing